# How to declare and use variables in Informix

Tags: informix

How can I declare and use variables in Informix Database. I'm using version 9.40uc7 and I would like to create two date variables read values into them then compare them using an if statement. 
eg.`DECLARE first_date, last_date DATE;`

However, I keep getting a syntax error on the declare line.

Comment: Unfortunately Informix doesn't support this kind of code as regular SQL (like T-SQL or PL/SQL) . Either the most actual version (12.10) . For that you need create a stored procedure :( ....